# Troubleshooting code for exact output - Finding the peak index

Tags: java, data-structures

I am facing issue while finding the peak index of array. I have tried solving using binary search. Don't know where I am going wrong. Though have successfully tested for some use cases.

```
class Solution {
    public int peakIndexInMountainArray(int[] arr) {
        int low=0;
        int high=arr.length-1;
        int mid=0;
        while(low<=high){
            mid = (low+high)/2;
            if (mid==0 | (arr[mid]>=arr[mid-1]) && (mid==high | arr[mid]>=arr[mid+1]))
                return mid;
            else if (mid>0 | arr[mid-1]>arr[mid]){
                low = mid+1;
            }
            high = mid-1;
        }return mid;       
    }
}
```

For the given input [0,2,1,0]

Output
2
Expected
1

**Edit for clarification on behalf of the poster:**

An array `arr` is a mountain if the following properties hold:

- `arr.length >= 3`
- There exists some `i` with `0 < i < arr.length - 1` such that:

  - `arr[0] < arr[1] < ... < arr[i - 1] < arr[i]`
  - `arr[i] > arr[i + 1] > ... > arr[arr.length - 1]`

Given a mountain array `arr`, return the index `i` such that `arr[0] < arr[1] < ... < arr[i - 1] < arr[i] > arr[i + 1] > ... > arr[arr.length - 1]`.

You must solve it in `O(log(arr.length))` time complexity.

Question taken from https://leetcode.com/problems/peak-index-in-a-mountain-array/

Comment: Binary search works only on sorted sequences. But your dataset in not sorted. It's seems to me like simply finding an index of first maximum element in array.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the values, each it is larger than the previous peak value, update the peak value and also the index. Return the index after completing.

```
public class Solution {
    public static int peakIndexInMountainArray(int[] arr) {
        int peakValue = 0;
        int peakIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int value = arr[i];
            if (value > peakValue) {
                peakValue = value;
                peakIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return peakIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Set 1: " + peakIndexInMountainArray(new int[]{0,1,2}));
        System.out.println("Set 2: " + peakIndexInMountainArray(new int[]{0,1,0}));
        System.out.println("Set 3: " + peakIndexInMountainArray(new int[]{0,2,1,0}));
        System.out.println("Set 4: " + peakIndexInMountainArray(new int[]{0,10,5,2}));
        System.out.println("Set 5: " + peakIndexInMountainArray(new int[]{0,100,500,2}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here the input is an array which is increasing uniformly first and then decreasing uniformly such that there is an highest element. Also, we have to implement this using Binary Search such that time complexity O(log(n)).

Comment: I've updated your question with these details, I assume this is from https://leetcode.com/problems/peak-index-in-a-mountain-array/ ? Maybe you could clarify the problems that you are having with your attempts and walk through your thinking process on your attempt. That would be help people help you a little more